# How to adjust spaceship's speed?

Tags: geometry

A spaceship is moving through 2-dimensional space by a series of jumps. Each jump consists of rotating right and flying forward. The angle of rotation is always the same and the distance flown forward is always the same. Thus, ship is flying circles around some point.

[image: Flying a ship]

There's a special point marked in space. The question is: with given angle, how far should the ship travel with each jump, such that circle he's flying will cross the point? (ship does not necessarily need to hit the point). Is there only one solution?

Ship may turn left or right, but this decision must be made before starting flying, later it always turns the same way each jump.

---

**Result**

Just for fun, this is my ship navigation algorithm, that was developed with amd's aid:

[image: Ship navigation]

Comment: Hint: you could perhaps consider the problem in the complex plane where rotation is multiplication by $\omega = e^{i\theta}$. The position after $n$ steps can be computed with geometric series.

Comment: What do you mean by “cross the point?”

Comment: @amd I mean, that the point will lie on the circle.

Comment: On the implied circle or on the actual broken-line path?

Comment: @amd On the circle itself.

Comment: Is the initial direction of the ship fixed or also a parameter?

Comment: @amd It is fixed, but if it simplifies the calculations, you may think of it a little bit differently: the angle of rotation may be, say, 5° and the ship will turn right or 355° and the ship will turn left. In general, the point is reachable only if it is on the right side of vertical line drawn through the initial position (when turning right). We may assume, that captain chose correct rotation to reach the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the initial heading of the ship is upwards (in the positive $y$ direction) and that $\theta$ increases clockwise, let $d$ be the hop distance. W.l.o.g. we can assume that the ship starts at the origin. Its first two hops will take it to $(d\sin\theta,d\cos\theta)$ and $(d\sin\theta+d\sin2\theta,d\cos\theta+d\cos2\theta)$. We now have three points on the implied circle and can immediately write down its equation in the form $$\det\begin{bmatrix}x^2+y^2 & x & y & 1 \\ x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0,$$ specifically, $$\det\begin{bmatrix}x^2+y^2 & x & y & 1 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
d^2 & d\sin\theta & d\cos\theta & 1 \\
d^2(\cos\theta+\cos2\theta)^2+d^2(\sin\theta+\sin2\theta)^2 & d(\sin\theta+\sin2\theta) & d(\cos\theta+\cos2\theta) & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$ which simplifies to $$x^2+y^2-\left(d\cot\frac\theta2\right)x+dy = 0.\tag{*}$$ (Subtract the third row from the fourth to simplify the computation of this determinant.) Solving this for $d$ yields $${x^2+y^2 \over x\cot\frac\theta2-y}.$$ If $d\lt0$, i.e., if $x\cot\frac\theta2\lt y$, that means that the circle would have to be traversed backwards: the target point can’t be reached with the given turn rate.

---

* This equation is equivalent to $\left(x-\frac12d\cot{\frac\theta2}\right)^2 + \left(y+\frac d2\right)^2 = \left({d \over 2\sin{\frac\theta2}}\right)^2 = {d^2\over 2-2\cos\theta}$, which could be useful if you need to know more about the circle.

Comment: Jusr for clarity, cot means cotangens? (I'm familiar with notation ctg)

Comment: Could you please break down the equations? Did you use form (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r^2=0?

Comment: @Spook Yes, $\cot$ means cotangent. For the equation, I just expanded the determinant and simplified the resulting expression. Converting that into the $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r^2=0$ form is trivial: expand the latter to get $x^2+y^2-2ax-2by+(a^2+b^2-r^2)=0$ and match up coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One final question, where did the determinant come from? I know of matrix-based way of solving series of linear equations, but that doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: @Spook The determinant actually comes from a system of linear equations. There’s a succinct explanation of the method [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~jwz120030/Teaching/PastCoursesUMBC/M221HS06/ProjectFiles/case3.pdf). It’s applicable to a broad variety of geometric problems.

Comment: That's simply awesome :) Thanks for the solution and the source :)

Comment: Are you sure, that angle increases counter-clockwise? Small positive values (like 5 degrees) yields positive X and Y and if the rotation was counter-clockwise, X should be negative. (by the way, this suits my needs even better).

Comment: @Spook Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: By the way, this may be approached also from the perspective of circle segment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

Comment: @Spook Write up an answer that uses it!